# Using jQuery and Web Services to send email

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to add sending email functionality to a pure html site. I created an ASP.Net project in VS 2017 and added the html files to it. On the page that has "Contact Us" form, I added jQuery to use web service to send email. I keep getting error and not sure how to debug it. I tested the method in web service separately and it works fine, it send out the email which means something must be wrong in my jQuery. I need help with this and see if anyone can spot what I am missing.

When I run it, I get status code 500 returned.

```
<section id="contact" class="bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-4">
                <h1>Contact us</h1>

                <form id="sendmail" method="POST" action="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputName" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="First and Last Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" aria-describedby="phoneHelp" placeholder="Contact Number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputMsg">Feedback/Questions</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMsg" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        debugger
        $("#sendmail").validate();

        if ($("#sendmail").valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/services/easg.asmx/SendEmail",
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{ 'Msg': '" + $("#inputMsg").val() + "', " + "'To': 'someone@somewhere.com'," + "'From': '" + $("#inputEmail").val() + "'," + "'Name': '" + $("#inputName").val() + "'," + "'Subject': 'Guide Feedback'," + "'Phone': '" + $("#inputPhone").val() + "'" + "}",
                dataType: "json",
                complete: function (transport) {
                    alert(transport.status);
                    if (transport.status == 200) {
                        alert('Your message was sent; thank you for your feedback');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Failed to send feedback; please try again later. Status Code: " + transport.status);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        //so that the page doesn't post back
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Web Service:

```
namespace EAStyleGuide
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    public class easg : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]

        private void SendEmail(string Msg, string To, string From, string Name, string Subject, string Phone)
        {
            using (var message = new MailMessage())
            {
                message.From = new MailAddress(From);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(To));
                message.Subject = Subject;
                message.Body = GetMailBody(From, Msg, Phone, Name);
                message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                message.IsBodyHtml = false;

                SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("mailrelay.blah.com");
                sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();

            try
            {
                sc.Send(message);
            }
            catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException FRE)
            {
            }
            catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception generalEx)
            {
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

There is a "Services" folder at the root of project with easg.asmx in it.

Comment: A 500 error means something failed on the server.  What was the actual response from the server?  What is the error message?  What is the resulting value of that data payload you're sending to the server?  Is it valid JSON?  When you debug the server-side code, where specifically does it fail?

Comment: that's the problem David, I put a break point in web service's "SendEmal" method but I don't hit it. Either jQuery code is bad and it doesn't call the web service or simply adding a break point in web service's method is not enough to stop at break point. However, when I put that method in a class and called it with some constant variables, it sent the email, so I think my SendEmail method is OK. How can I check the actual response from server while debugging in VS?

Comment: Check your browser's debugging tools.  There you can observe the HTTP requests/responses involved in the page, including the AJAX call.  You'll want to see what the actual response from the server is.

Comment: I intercepted "transport" variable and its respnseText was "Unknown web method SendEmail. Parameter name: methodName"

Comment: Then it's not finding the web method to begin with.  Does `UseHttpGet = true` restrict that web method to *only* GET requests?  Because you're sending a POST request.

Comment: David, please add your response not as a comment and I will mark it as answer. That was one issue; I had to set useHttpGet to false. Also I had stupidly set the method to be private instead of public. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging as a result of comments on the question above...

> respnseText was "Unknown web method SendEmail. Parameter name: methodName"

This means that the framework isn't able to find the web method at all based on the request being made.  Looking closer, the web method appears to be restricted to GET requests:

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
```

However, you're making a POST request:

```
type: "POST",
```

You'll need to change one or the other.  Which is up to you.